# Not able to access a port on ec2 instance for an Angular app

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am working on an angular app using the angular cli to set things up. Running the `ng serve` command spawns a server at this address `<my_ec2_host_name>:4200`. When I try to access the page on the browser it doesn't work (connection timed out error). I believe this is because of security reasons so I added the following rule to my security groups for the ec2 instance:

[image]

Port 4200 should now be accessible but I still can't get the page to load. Can someone think of how to get this to work?

Comment: Check NACL (if you did not update them, then it's okay). Have you attached a public (Elastic) IP to the EC2 instance? Check iptables in the instance.

Comment: Is the server listening only on localhost?  i.e. what does a `netstat -na | grep 4200` return?  If it is something like 127.0.0.1:4200 then your server is only listening on the localhost interface, not all interfaces.

Answer (score 7):

Start angular with below command.

```
ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check
```

it will disable host check and allow to access with IP

Answer (score 1):

You can set up the host option like this:

```
ng serve -host 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

The steps you are doing are correct for opening a port via Security Groups in the EC2 console. Make sure you are modifying the correct security group, and make sure that your changes have been saved.

Your container may have additional firewalls in place, so you will want to check the OS documentation. For Example, RHEL uses iptables as a further security measure: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/sect-Security_Guide-IPTables.html.

Comment: Should have mentioned I'm running Ubuntu OS.

Answer (score 0):

That looks correct. Are you sure that your server is running and listening for connections?

You should ssh to that server and verify that the page can be loaded locally. Eg:

```
curl http://<YOUR HOST IP ADDRESS>:4200
eg: curl http://54.164.10.123:4200
```

You should be careful to use the public ip address (eg: IPv4 Public IP when you're in the EC2 console). I've run into problems in the past where I've got a server listening on one IP address (often localhost) and not the public ip address.

Also maybe a problem: Is your host inside a VPC of some sort?

Comment: Yea the server is running, I can access `http://<YOUR HOST IP ADDRESS>` because I have apache running too. I can also SSH into it correctly, that's where I'm running the `ng serve` command from.

Comment: I don't think so about the VPC since I don't even know what that is haha. I'm just using the default setup.

Comment: you have apache serving on port 4200 as well as 80?

Comment: No apache is running on 80, nothing else is running on 4200. Anyway I just stopped apache in case it was causing conflicts and still same issue persists.

Comment: one more thing: the fact that you are getting a connection timeout and not a connection refused suggests that your inbound rules are correct and that it's a problem with the service running on port 4200.